# Configuring auto-complete when it is installed as a package

Tags: emacs, autocomplete

I used to have the following line in `auto-complete`:

```
(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/auto-complete/dict")
(ac-config-default)
```

but now that I installed `auto-complete` as an Emacs package, I don't have an `auto-complete folder` in my `.emacs.d` directory anymore, so the second line above does not work.

This leads me to two questions:

- More generally, where are packages installed?
- How should I adapt my `add-to-list` line now that I have auto-complete installed as a package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default (in newer versions of `auto-complete`) the directory used will the the one in the site-lisp folder where emacs installed the package so that line is not required. Simply placing

```
 (setq-default ac-sources
               '(ac-source-abbrev ac-source-dictionary
                                  ac-source-words-in-same-mode-buffers))
```

In your `.emacs` will let `auto-complete` know the sources you want for completion and the dictionary file will be placed appropriately.

If you want a custom dictionary (at least what I did) was

```
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directiories "~/.dict")
```

Just make sure the directory you put exists.

EDIT: Forgot to mention that this is only if you want to add custom dictionaries to auto-complete (Java object higlighting or custom keywords, etc...). The language ones are enabled by default.

Comment: how should one name files inside `~/.dict` directory to make `auto-complete` pick up that custom dictionary?